# Drop down list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a `<select>` field, which shows a hidden div on selecting a list item.

There are tree items in the `<select>` and each item shows the hidden div.

What I need is when I have selected the 3rd item and I refresh the page, the 3rd item should no longer be selected, but it should change to the 1st item.

I have tried `selected="selected"` in the `<option>` code but it did not work.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#column_select").change(function() {         
    $('div[id^=layout_select]').hide();
    $('.'+this.value).show();  
});

});
//]]>  

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- this controls the selection of columns --> 
<select name="column_selec" id="column_select">     
    <option value="col1" selected="selected">1 column</option>     
    <option value="col2">2 column</option>     
    <option value="col3">3 column</option> 
</select>   


<!-- this controls the selection of columns -->  

<!-- if '1 column' is selected this div is shown --> 
<div id="layout_select1" class="col1">You only have one column!</div>  

<!-- if '2 column' is selected this div is shown --> 
<div id="layout_select2" class="col2" style="display:none">    
    <input type="radio" id="'.$option[0].'" name="'.$option[0].'" size="25" value="lay1" '.$layout1.' />imaage1
    <input type="radio" id="'.$option[0].'" name="'.$option[0].'" size="25" value="lay2" '.$layout2.' />imaage2    </div>  
<!-- if '3 column' is selected this div is shown -->
<div id="layout_select3" class="col3" style="display:none">
    <input type="radio" id="'.$option[0].'" name="'.$option[0].'" size="25" value="lay3" '.$layout3.' />imaage3
    <input type="radio" id="'.$option[0].'" name="'.$option[0].'" size="25" value="lay4" '.$layout4.' />imaage4    
    <input type="radio" id="'.$option[0].'" name="'.$option[0].'" size="25" value="lay5" '.$layout5.' />imaage5
</div>
```

Comment: Refreshing a page reloads it, setting everything back to the original state. If you want to preserve state between page refreshes, then you need to store the change at the server and output the new page when it is loaded, or store the change locally via Javascript `localStorage` (HTML5).

Comment: You could make that into a form and submit it to the current page, then check `$_POST['whatever']` to see if option 3 was suggested. If it was, select option 1. If not, don't do anything. This is pretty much one method you can use, like Matt H suggested. If you don't want PHP, [localStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) works.

Answer (score 0):

try this code , this will select the first option in the drop down when page will refresh

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#column_select').val('col1');
 });
```